# Non-ASCII characters are being displayed in the question section

Tags: bug, design

Non-ASCII characters are appearing in the question section. These characters are also visible in both the New Question and Edit modes.

Please refer to the screenshot for clarification:

[image: Non-ASCII characters]

Comment: Not seeing either symptom ([[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsUnN.png)], [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq7f8.png)]) or anything in the source that could contribute to this. Does it happen in an incognito window, a different browser, and one without extensions and/or userscripts enabled?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Seems intermittent issue, I suspect that the font-family wasn't load for some time. Not incognito window and no extensions/userscripts used.

Comment: It seems an odd symptom that I couldn't reproduce on really, really, really crappy hotel wi-fi today. If you're right and you're on a connection so slow that things like CSS or a whole series of fallback fonts can't render, not sure what any site can do to protect you from that. The font list for `--ff-mono` is pretty simple: `ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;`